# need help in rebase in github

Tags: git, github, git-branch, rebase

I am new to github and made a mistake on my first day.
I was supposed to edit code on one of the feature branches
accidentally, I checkout a different feature branch and added changes there and pushed it.

Mistake:

- I cloned from `master`. Checked out a different feature branch. Added my updated python codefile. Ran `git commit` and pushed the changes. It resulted in many objects being updated instead of just one.

> ```
> git clone https://github.aop-site.com/AOP/AOP_DEPT.git
> git checkout feature/BARC-125
> git add compute_code.py
> git commit - m "qwsasa"
> git push
> ```

What I should have done:

- I was supposed to create a different feature branch, check that out and add changes to it and push the same.

> ```
>   git clone https://github.aop-site.com/AOP/AOP_DEPT.git
>   git checkout feature/BARC-149
>   git add compute_code.py
> ```

Request :
How do I fix the changes (mistake section) which I have did in mistake section?

Comment: All you have done in both cases was to stage just a single file.  There is nothing permanent about that; just unstage and move on using the correct branch.

Comment: another developer was working on that feature. also i did - git commit and git push

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your branch you accidentally added code to with to a previous commit with 
 `git reset --hard 2f93ndms` - "2f93ndms" being the branch commit, visible on github next to the comits on that branch.

Once that branch is reset you can re-push with `git push -f **origin** **branch-name**` 
the `-f` is a force flag, as you won't have the code you previously pushed as a mistake it won't let you normally push to the repo. `-f` Please do be careful when using this.

If you need to rebase, this is the order I go.

1. Checkout your `master` branch, `git pull` if you have a github repo to ensure it's at the latest version.
2. checkout your feature branch
3. `git rebase -r master`
4. If you have conflicts, correct them and add the file with `git add db/schema.rb` - example
5. If the rebase paused because of conflicts, continue with `git rebase --continue`

Answer (score 0):

Once code has been pushed then its an extremely bad practice to try to modify the history of that code (unless this is a branch you work on yourself alone, but in that case creating another branch is much better)

The best solution in this scenario would be to revert the change and push that, later checkout from the new branch - with the changes reverted - and re introduce the changes you done in the old branch.

If reintroducing the changes is tedious then you can either revert the revert, or cherry pick the commits you need.